# How can I traverse through User and UserProfile in django?

Tags: python, django, models

I want to show users' usernames, first names and last name from the User model and then show the matching city and country from UserProfile.

These are the models:

```
# this is the model for city
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="", unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Scotland")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(City, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @property
    def avg_rating(User):
        return self.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

This is the view:

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.order_by('-userrating')[:5]
    user_profile_list = UserProfile.objects.all()
    city_list = City.objects.order_by('-name')[:5]

    context_dict = {"users": user_list, "cities" : city_list, "profiles" : user_profile_list}

    return render(request, "index.html", context_dict)
```

and this is template:

```
            {% if users %}
                <ul>
                    {% for user in users %}
                    {% for profile in profiles %}

                        <li><p><a href="user/{{ user.slug }}"
                                  style="color:rgba(0,0,200,1.00)">{{ user.username }} {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</a>
                            from <a href="city/{{ user.city.slug }}"
                                    style="color:rgba(0,0,200,1.00)">{{ profile.city.name }}</a>, {{ user.city.country }}, {{ user.avg_rating }}
                        </p></li>

                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

However, it shows one user with all cities instead of the matching city.

like this:

> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Stolkholm, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Stolkholm, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Sao Paulo, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Paris, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Glasgow, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Madrid, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Madrid, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Stolkholm, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Glasgow, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Madrid, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Paris, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Stolkholm, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Glasgow, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Madrid, ,
>
> crystalgillespie Crystal Gillespie from Munich, ,

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From a user object, you can follow the foreign key to the profile with `user.userprofile`, and from there, get to the city with `user.userprofile.city`.

Here's a simplified version of your template to demonstrate.

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username }}
    {{ user.userprofile.profilepic }}
    {{ user.userprofile.city.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this means that you don't need to fetch the profiles and cities in your view. You can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to reduce the number of sql queries:

```
def index(request):
    user_list = User.objects.select_related()[:5]
    context_dict = {"users": user_list}
    return render(request, "index.html", context_dict)
```

Comment: it doesn't work when I use something like: user.userprofile.city.name it just shows blank even though my db includes cities in each user profile

Comment: Does `{{ user.userprofile }}` or `{{ user.userprofile.profilepic }}` show anything?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then. Maybe you are looping through users that do not have a user profile.

Comment: I'm sorry there was something wrong with my data. All your solutions work perfectly. Thanks!